# Python: generate a different random choice when importing from module (different python file) - Keep getting same output

Tags: python, selenium, random, module

I have a code for choosing different comments from a list, which is stored in a separate python file, like comments.py:

```
import random

theitems = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

commentpick = random.choice(theitems)
```

I have the following code in the main file:

```
from comments import commentpick

for a in commentboxes:
   a.send_keys(commentpick)
```

However the same comments will be returned for all the 'a' in commentboxes:
[eg. 5 inputs, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']

It only works if i import random and do it on the main file, like this:

```
for a in commentboxes:
       a.send_keys(random.choice(theitems))
```

then the result will be varied,  [eg. 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'f']

Is there any way that I will be able to write a.send_keys(commentpick) directly without doing the random.choice in the main file but still get different results each time? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put

> commentpick = random.choice(theitems)

in function, by that you can call random function each time to call the function you build

for example:
comments.py

```
def commentpick():
    theitems = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
    commentpick = random.choice(theitems)
    return commentpick
```

and in your main file:

```
from comments import commentpick

for a in commentboxes:
    a.send_keys(commentpick())
```

your problem is you just called once and save the value and used many times.